# Firebase storage API triggers twice

Tags: firebase, rxjs, firebase-storage, angularfire2, angular-observable

I am trying to store my file using Google Firebase storage API but the pipe is getting executed twice. Any ideas to make it triggered one time only?

```js
// def
task: AngularFireUploadTask;
storage: AngularFireStorage;

// code
this.task = this.storage.upload(path, file, { customMetadata });
    return this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(doc => {
            console.log('me'); // THIS IS PRINTED TWICE
            return doc;
        })
    );
```

Comment: During an `UploadTask`, there will be multiple `TaskEvent.STATE_CHANGED` events as the upload is performed (e.g. at 13%, at 42%, at 100%). Each of these will invoke chained observers that use `pipe()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/angular/angularfire/blob/master/docs/storage/storage.md#monitoring-upload-percentage), you can expect that the pipe will receive multiple snapshots as the upload progresses.  Each of these snapshots contain some information about the status of the upload as it progresses over time.

If you just want to know when the upload is complete, take the code from the sample in the documentation, which gets the download URL after the upload is complete:

```
task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
    finalize(() => this.downloadURL = fileRef.getDownloadURL() )
)
```

Comment: Yes i ended up doing this. Crazy API's to make people lives easier :)

Comment: It's not crazy - it's delivering progress updates so you can do things like populate a progress bar, which is very common.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the operator `take()`:

> Emits only the first count values emitted by the source Observable.
>
> Returns
> `MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T>`: An Observable that emits only the first count values emitted by the source Observable, or all of the values from the source if the source emits fewer than count values.

Example:

```js
return this.task.snapshotChanges().pipe(
  take(1),
  map(doc => {
    console.log('me');
    return doc;
  })
)
```

https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/filtering/take.html

Comment: Shouldn't `take` be the last operator?

Comment: Wouldn't [`last`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/last) be a better candidate for this? Then the `map` will only be invoked when the upload completes.

Comment: Yes `last()` can also be used @samthecodingman anyway OP didn't answer yet to see if they tried this or no

Comment: @all: Putting last or first `take` didn't worked (No reasons why). I changed the code to `this.task
            .snapshotChanges()
            .pipe(
              finalize(() => {...}))` . Now i am getting no second call inside finalize.

Comment: The OP probably does not want just the first emitted snapshot.  They probably actually want just the one that indicates the upload is complete, which will be the last one.